# How to use Ruby's self keyword

Tags: ruby, instance, self

From what I understand about `self`, it refers to the current instance of the class.

Isn't this the default behaviour at all times anyways? For example, isn't

```
self.var_one = method(args)
```

equivalent to

```
var_one = method(args)
```

If so, what is the use of `self`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In most cases `self.foo` is indeed redundant because you can just write `foo` for the same effect, but in this case it is not and the `self` is required.

`var_one = method(args)` will create a local variable called `var_one`, it will not call any method or do anything else to `self`.

`self.var_one = method(args)` will call the method `var_one=` on `self` with the argument `method(args)`.

Another case where the use of `self` is non-optional would be if you want to pass it as an argument to a method, i.e. `some_method(self)` - you can't do that without the `self` keyword.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused. How can `var_one=` be a method? I meant for `var_one` to be a variable, and assign the result of the method named `method` to that variable.

Comment: @Ankit: It can be a method by being a method. Sorry if that's a bit of a non-answer, but I don't really know how else to answer that. If you want `var_one` to be a local variable, putting `self.` in front of it is wrong and will not do what you want.

Comment: @Ankit Soni: If you send any message to `self` (e.g., `self.foo`) it is calling the `foo` method of your class.  `var_one=` is just a setter method.  If you want `var_one` to be a variable, you must not use `self` (which is only useful for calling methods).  If you're looking for instance variables then you simply prefix an identifier with `@` (e.g., `@var_one`)

Comment: OK I understand how `var_one=` is the setter method. Now ,even in this case, wouldnt `var_one=` also call the same setter method of that same instance of the object as `self.var_one=`?

Comment: Wait are you saying that `var = "bla"` exists only as a setter method in ruby? i.e there is no assignment operator, and this writing `a = b` is only a convenient way of writing `a.set(b)`?

Comment: @Ankit: No. If you write `var = "bla"` this will always create a local variable and never invoke a setter method. If you write `foo.var = "bla"`, it will call the setter method `var=` on `foo`. So to invoke the `var=` setter method on `self`, you need to write `self.var = "bla"`. Writing `var = "bla"` will *not* suffice as it will simply create a local variable.

Comment: @sepp2k So writing `var = "bla"` will make a local variable `var` and set it to `"bla"`. Isn't that what my setter method would do for me anyways?
Sorry I'm asking so many questions about this by the way, I'm just trying to figure this out and be done with it.

Comment: @Ankit: Your setter method will do what ever you define it to do. However it will almost certainly not create a local variable named `var`, as that variable, being local, would only live inside that setter method and thus have no effect. If you defined the setter method using `attr_accessor`, what it will do is create an *instance variable* called `@var`. So in that specific case `@var = "foo"` and `self.var = "foo"` would do the same thing. However `var = "foo"` would not.

Answer (score 127):

There are several important uses, most of which are basically to disambiguate between instance methods, class methods, and variables.

First, this is the best way to define class methods:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    "class method bar"
  end

  def bar
    "instance method bar"
  end
end

Foo.bar  #returns "class method bar"

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar #returns "instance method bar"
```

Also, within instance methods `self` refers to the instance, within class methods it refers to the class, and it can always be used to distinguish from local variables.

```
class Bar
  def self.foo
    "foo!"
  end

  def baz
    "baz!"
  end

  def self.success
    foo #looks for variable foo, doesn't find one, looks for class method foo, finds it, returns "foo!"
  end

  def self.fail
    baz #looks for variable baz, doesn't find one, looks for class method baz, doesn't find one, raises exception
  end

  def instance_success
    baz #looks for variable baz, doesn't find one, looks for instance method baz, finds it, returns "baz!"
  end

  def instance_fail
    foo #looks for variable foo, doesn't find one, looks for instance method foo, doesn't find one, raises exception
  end

  def local_variable
    baz = "is my favorite method"
    baz #looks for variable baz, finds it, returns "is my favorite method"
  end

  def disambiguate
    baz = " is my favorite method"
    self.baz + baz #looks for instance method baz, finds it, looks for local variable baz, finds it, returns "baz! is my favorite method"
  end
end
```

So, in the end, you can avoid using `self` in many cases, but it's often helpful to use it to make sure that you don't inadvertently create naming conflicts later on. Sometimes those can create bugs that are very hard to find. In the end it's often a matter of personal style.

---

As noted in the comments, one more really important thing:

In a class, if you have a method like this:

```
def bar=(string)
  ...
end
```

And in another method you call:

```
def other_method
  bar = "abcd"
end
```

It isn't going to call your `bar=` method, it's going to create a local variable `bar`. So, in this case you use `self` to tell Ruby not to create a local variable:

```
def other_method
  self.bar = "abcd"
end
```

The same thing applies if you want to take an argument with the name of a method:

```
def example
  ...
end

def other_thing(example)
  self.example(example)
end
```

If you left off `self` Ruby would assume you meant the local variable with the same name.

So, in general, `self` in method names is used to distinguish between class and instance variables, and everywhere else you use it when Ruby needs help distinguishing between method calls and local variables or local variable assignment.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is a more thorough answer, except that it doesn't include the assignment caveat.  There is also a good blog article on the usages: http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby which includes, specifically, assignment.  You can't call an assignment method without using self (as noted in the first answer).

Comment: Very helpful for Java guys =)

Comment: probably, it's better to outline the principle that "you can only access class variable/method inside a class method"

Comment: @fengd Of-course you can call class variable/method from instance method  using  self.class.class_method  "  class Person
 

  def self.class_method
    'golbal variable'
  end  

  def show
    self.class.class_method
  end
end

person = Person.new
puts person.show

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example:

```
def run miles
  self.miles = miles
end
```

In this case `self` will help. In most cases `self` is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

One other use of `self` is to declare class methods (similar to static methods in Java).

```
class foo
 def self.bar
  #do class related stuff here
 end
end
```

That being said, you could also have used `def foo.bar` instead for the method signature.