# How can I call a method when an object is initialized?

Tags: ruby

Rather than calling `cop_log.read_spreadsheet` how can I call the method `read_spreadsheet` directly inside my class when I use `ChangeOrderLog.new('path/to/file')`?

`cop_log.read_spreadsheet` populates the `@cop_log` hash with the data from an excel spreadsheet, is there any way I can populate my hash from within my ChangeOrderLog class instead of outside of it?

```
require 'creek'

class ChangeOrderLog
  attr_reader :creek, :sheet
  attr_accessor :cop_log
  def initialize(file)
    @creek = Creek::Book.new file
    @sheet= @creek.sheets[0]
    @cop_log = {}
  end
  def read_spreadsheet
    sheet.rows.each { |row| cop_log.merge!(row) }
  end
  def job_number
    return cop_log['G1']
  end
end

cop_log = ChangeOrderLog.new('path/to/file')
cop_log.read_spreadsheet
puts cop_log.job_number
```

Comment: Put it in `initialize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object already exists by the time `initialize` is called, it just hasn't been initialized yet. So you can call methods in `initialize`, but do it after the rest of the object has been initialized, especially `@sheet`.

```
  def initialize(file)
    @creek = Creek::Book.new file
    @sheet= @creek.sheets[0]
    @cop_log = {}

    read_spreadsheet
  end
```

`read_spreadsheet` is shorthand for `self.read_spreadsheet`. [`self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669527/use-of-ruby-self-keyword) is the object `initialize` (or any other method) was called with. In this case `self` is your freshly created `ChangeOrderLog` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can call methods inside of other methods, `initialize` is no exception:

```
def initialize(file)
    @creek = Creek::Book.new file
    @sheet= @creek.sheets[0]
    @cop_log = {}
    read_spreadsheet
end
```