# Why use "self" to access ActiveRecord/Rails model properties?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Throughout my application `self.` is not necessary to refer to a User's name. `name` works fine.

Why does the following code require `self` to work as intended?

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :validate_name

def validate_name
    if self.name.nil? || self.name.empty?
        self.name= "Mr. No Name"
    end
end
```

By the way, I know that `validates_presence_of` can be used to prevent the save, but I want to save with a default if no name is given.

Rails 3.0.7.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Often the use of `self` is to force Ruby to recognize that as a method call and not mis-interpret it as a variable. Without prior knowledge of a method called `day=`, then `day = "x"` looks to Ruby like a variable assignment. `self.day = "x"` is always a method call.

The reason this is trouble is because the `name` and `name=` methods are added dynamically after the User class file has been parsed. The first thing Rails does when using a model is make methods for the associated database fields, but this happens after your `user.rb` file is parsed.

Comment: Sorry, `self.day` was supposed to be `self.name`! I updated the question.

Comment: Nit: Ruby will never take `x = y` to be a method call. It is always a direct variable (or constant, depending on case) assignment. The form `x` (as expression) depends on if there is such an `x` in scope (as a variable) or not.

Comment: If `name` and `name=` are added dynamically after the class file is parsed, then are there times when `name` means `self.name` and other times when `name` is a local variable?

Comment: And, does that mean that using `self.name` instead of `name` is a best practice?

Comment: @BSeven The expression `name` means "the local variable name" *if and only if* `name` is already bound (assigned to). At all other times it means `self.name`. The expression `name = y` is always an assignment of `y` to *the variable* `name`. I prefer to just avoid overloading names used. `obj.attr = v` is always required for setters. ;-)

Comment: Nit 2: `class` in Ruby is no more "special" than dynamic methods that are added later. It is just an expression and does not "add context" to how Ruby later handles `x` or `x=` (as this will *never* be a method call, even if "defined within the `class` expression".) In any case, still a +1, even if I find the response a wee bit misleading in places :-)

Comment: I use `self` a lot out of formality. I don't know if it's a best practice, per-se, but it's no worse than `this` in JavaScript.

Comment: @pst Perhaps you should edit the answer to reflect your (correct)  comments? `:)`.