# Rails - build associated record with additional params in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have has_many_through relationship:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :schedule_tasks
    has_many :tasks, :through => :schedule_tasks

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :schedule_tasks
    has_many :schedules, :through => :schedule_tasks
```

When I create the record, the join table (schedule_tasks) record that's created only populates the bare minimum fields to make the join, in this case, :schedule_id and :task_id, I need an additional field - :day_id filled as well (this field is also in the Task model, but right now this is how I need to do it:

```
def create
    @schedule = Schedule.find(task_params['schedule_id'])
    @task = @schedule.tasks.create(task_params)
    @schedule_task = @schedule.schedule_tasks.where(task_id: @task.id, schedule_id: @schedule.id).first
    @schedule_task.day_id = @task.day_id
    @schedule_task.save
    redirect_to @schedule
end
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally stay away from [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) as they can result in very messy spaghetti logic, but this seems to be a decent use case.

```
class ScheduleTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :schedule

  before_save :set_day_id

  def set_day_id
    self.day_id = task.day_id
  end  
end
```

Comment: I tried adding that, but it does not seem to be executing?  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `schedule_tasks` (`schedule_id`, `task_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 105, '2015-04-27 17:21:54', '2015-04-27 17:21:54')
   (5.8ms)  COMMIT

Comment: Looks like `self` is needed to force AR to recognize it as a method call instead of a local instance variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127393/why-use-self-to-access-activerecord-rails-model-properties/10127425#10127425