# Rails: Adding methods to ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm writing my first rather simple Ruby on Rails (3.2) application. The idea is to manage email accounts. The schema is rather simple:

```
t.string   "email"
t.string   "password"
```

The ActiveRecord model is defined as:

```
class Mailuser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password
```

I've been using scaffolding with all the `form_for(@mailuser)` and `@mailuser.update_attributes(params[:mailuser])` magic. That works well.

Now the quirk is that the user should be allowed to only edit the *user* part (e.g. "foo") of an email while the *domain* (e.g. "example.org") must stay untouched. The *email* field however contains the complete email address (e.g. "foo@example.org"). So in the edit form I don't display the fields

- email
- password

but rather

- userpart
- password

where the `userpart` is shown as `@mailuser.userpart` (editable) + *domain* (not editable).

So I thought I'd solve that by adding a getter and setter for the user part like this:

```
class Mailuser < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :email, :password

   # Getter for the user part (left of '@')
   def userpart
      email.split('@')[0]
   end

   # Setter for the user part (left of '@')
   def userpart=(new_userpart)
      email = email.sub(/(.+)@/, new_userpart+"@")
   end
```

In fact getting the `@mailuser.userpart` works well. And it's even displayed properly in the `form_for(@mailuser)`. But a problem occurs when saving the form using `@mailuser.update_attributes(params[:mailuser])` in the controller's `update` method. Rails apparently tries to update the `@mailuser` object from the attributes made available through `attr_accessible`. But the `userpart` attribute does not reflect an actual database field.

So I wonder what is the proper way to add such methods to ActiveRecord models to add functionality? I'm used to Pylons (a Python MVC framework) and I could use such additional methods all the way.

(In fact you wonder: I can't split the user and domain parts by changing the database schema. The database is used by other applications so I'm stuck with the way it looks.)

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: can you post your form?

Comment: The form is basically (sorry, stackoverflow doesn't allow it to be nicer)
    <%= form_for(@mailuser) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :userpart %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :userpart %>@<%= @mailuser.domain.name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the solution are *virtual attributes*. In my example the actual solution was:

- assign `self.email` instead of `email` to change the value of the instance variable. Using just `email` just created a local variable. (I wasn't aware that leaving off the `self` is just a convenience feature of Ruby that can lead to confusion as in this case.)
- use `attr_accessible :userpart` in the model

This is well explained in the (non-free) http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised?autoplay=true screencast. I wonder where *virtual attributes* are explained in the official Rails documentation.

Comment: I wonder though what the difference between `@email` and `self.email` is in the model. Is that a Rails specialty? Because I thought that both mean the same in Ruby classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183664/why-isnt-self-always-needed-in-ruby-rails-activerecord

Answer (score 2):

You want to add `attr_accessible :userpart` so that userpart can be updated by update_attributes mass assignment.

Added: userpart is an example of a *virtual attribute* if you want to ask Mr. Google for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you - googling for _virtual attribute_ helped me a lot. Apparently I get working code if I replace `email = email.sub(/(.+)@/, new_userpart+"@")` by `self.email = email.sub(/(.+)@/, new_userpart+"@")`. I thought that _self_ refers to class attributes instead of instance attributes. So I don't understand why this works. But apparently it does.

Comment: You might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464793/what-is-the-right-way-to-override-a-setter-method-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Thanks. That refers to overriding the behavior of attributes. I rather intended to add virtual attributes. But thanks for the link.

Comment: Yeah, I learned something about self and virtual attributes! Good question.