# Ruby (Rails) variable scope

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables

I'm quite new with Ruby language and Rails. I'm currently building some simple user registration process. When I used these codes Rails throws: 
**no implicit conversion from nil to string**

Here's the original code:

```
require 'digest'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :encrypt_password

  protected
  def encrypt_password
    return if password.blank?
    password = encrypt(password)
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string)
  end
end
```

But it works if I changed this line `password = encrypt(password)`, to `self.password = encrypt(password)`. I'm just curious, what's wrong with the first code?

Comment: You should also read through http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183664/why-isnt-self-always-needed-in-ruby-rails-activerecord

Answer (score 3):

Ruby doesn't allow using implicit `self.` with the `person=` type of method.
That is because it considers you're setting a local variable. So it doesn't relies on self.

You need to explicitely specify `self.password =`.